# How do I dump a groovy representation to YAML and avoid having untagged nodes?

Tags: groovy, yaml, snakeyaml

I want to dump the following structure to a YAML file:

```
public class TestSuite {
    String name
    List testCases = []
}
```

Where the list of test cases are this class:

```
class TestCase {
    String name
    String id
}
```

What I want it to look like is this:

```
name: Carrier Handling and Traffic
testCases:
- name: Call setup by UE
  id: DCM00000001
```

But it ends up looking like this:

```
name: Carrier Handling and Traffic
testCases:
- !!com.package.path.TestCase
  name: Call setup by UE
  id: DCM00000001
```

I guess it has to do with the fact that the List isn't a tagged data structure but I can't figure out how I can get the name of the test case to represent the object. Tips?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does defining `TestSuite` as:

```
public class TestSuite {
    String name
    List<TestCase> testCases = []
}
```

Get you closer to the result you want?  Not used SnakeYaml myself though...

---

#### Edit

Had some free time, and came up with this standalone test script:

```
@Grab( 'org.yaml:snakeyaml:1.10' )
import org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml
import org.yaml.snakeyaml.representer.Representer
import java.beans.IntrospectionException
import org.yaml.snakeyaml.introspector.Property

public class TestSuite {
    String name
    List<TestCase> testCases = []
}

class TestCase {
    String name
    String id
}

class NonMetaClassRepresenter extends Representer {
  protected Set<Property> getProperties( Class<? extends Object> type ) throws IntrospectionException {
    super.getProperties( type ).findAll { it.name != 'metaClass' }
  }
}

TestSuite suite = new TestSuite( name:'Carrier Handling and Traffic' )
suite.testCases << new TestCase( name:'Call setup by UE', id:'DCM00000001' ) 

println new Yaml( new NonMetaClassRepresenter() ).dumpAsMap( suite )
```

Which prints:

```
name: Carrier Handling and Traffic
testCases:
- id: DCM00000001
  name: Call setup by UE
```

Comment: Hmm, I don't really get what's going on here. You override the default Representer to not ever output the name of the metaClass? Isn't there an easier way?

Comment: Not that I can find...  Can you post how you are outputting the yaml you show in your question?  As I said, I've not really used snakeyaml

Comment: I just dump it straight out without using a Representer. I was rather thinking that I've misunderstood something with YAML itself, but I can't seem to wrap my head around the standard enough to understand why it ends up looking like that in the first place.

Comment: @Fylke Looks like snakeyaml puts a [fully qualified type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML#Casting_data_types) in so that it can be cast back to its original type when the YAML file is deserialized...  I had to use the custom Representer as all Groovy object have a metaClass, and in my tests, this was getting put into the YAML as well (so my NonMetaClassRepresenter filters it out)

Comment: Ah, now I'm starting to understand. So that's why it "works" when I just use a regular List of Strings and not a custom Groovy class. Then your solution sounds like the only sensible alternative, thanks!

Comment: To any future comers - this method worked for me and was better than the `JavaBeanRepresenter` example in the SnakeYAML docs.